# Having trouble understanding lstm use in tensorflow code sample

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Why is the `pred` variable being calculated before any of the training iterations occur? I would expect that a `pred` would be generated (through the `RNN()` function) during **each** pass through of the data for every iteration?

There must be something I am missing. Is `pred` something like a function object? I have looked at the docs for `tf.matmul()` and that returns a tensor, not a function.

Full source: https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/recurrent_network.py

Here is the code:

```
def RNN(x, weights, biases):

    # Prepare data shape to match `rnn` function requirements
    # Current data input shape: (batch_size, n_steps, n_input)
    # Required shape: 'n_steps' tensors list of shape (batch_size, n_input)

    # Unstack to get a list of 'n_steps' tensors of shape (batch_size, n_input)
    x = tf.unstack(x, n_steps, 1)

    # Define a lstm cell with tensorflow
    lstm_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0)

    # Get lstm cell output
    outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

    # Linear activation, using rnn inner loop last output
    return tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights['out']) + biases['out']

pred = RNN(x, weights, biases)

# Define loss and optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Evaluate model
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred,1), tf.argmax(y,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow code has two distinct phases. First, you build a "dependency graph", which contains all of the operations that you will use. Note that during this phase you are not processing any data. Instead, you are simply defining the operations you want to occur. Tensorflow is taking note of the dependencies between the operations.

For example, in order to compute the `accuracy`, you'll need to first compute `correct_pred`, and to compute `correct_pred` you'll need to first compute `pred`, and so on.

So all you have done in the code shown is to tell tensorflow what operations you want. You've saved those in a "graph" data structure (that's a tensorflow data structure that basically is a bucket that contains all the mathematical operations and tensors).

Later you will run operations on the data using calls to `sess.run([ops], feed_dict={inputs})`.

When you call `sess.run` notice that you have to tell it what you want from the graph. If you ask for `accuracy`:

```
   sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={inputs})
```

Tensorflow will try to compute accuracy. It will see that `accuracy` depends on `correct_pred`, so it will try to compute that, and so on through the dependency graph that you defined.

The error you're making is that you think `pred` in the code you listed is computing something. It's not. The line:

```
   pred = RNN(x, weights, biases)
```

only defined the operation and its dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a ton. One last question: Isn't `RNN()` a function that returns a tensor. So therefore `pred` should be a tensor right? From your answer it is not and I'm not seeing how. How is `pred` not using the `RNN()` function to return a tensor? Is there some syntax I'm missing?

Comment: Indeed it returns a tensor. But a tensor is just an object representing some computation that will occur in the future. If you print that tensor you will see meta information about it such as its expected shape (if it knows the shape, it might not, the shape might be dynamic). You will *not* get a value of the tensor. If you want the *value* of the tensor you'll need to ask tensorflow to actually compute it with `mytensors_value_as_a_numpy_array = sess.run(mytensor)`. You need to pass the tensor to TF compute it. You can keep the tensor in hand as you do in this code, or you can look them up.